# Simulate touch command with Java

Tags: java, file, touch

I want to change modification timestamp of a binary file. What is the best way for doing this?

Would opening and closing the file be a good option? (I require a solution where the modification of the timestamp will be changed on every platform and JVM).

Comment: Someone should submit this as an enhancement request to unix4j: https://github.com/tools4j/unix4j

Comment: I do not understand the the relation between the title and the question here?

Comment: @Lealo see [Unix touch command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_(Unix))

Comment: The title is confusing, as is the accepted answer.  Touch *creates* a file if it does not exist.  The title should be changed.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The File class has a [setLastModified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setLastModified%28long%29) method. That is what ANT does.

Comment: Except that there is known Android bug, and File.setLastModified doesn't do anything on most Android devices.

Comment: And except shell `touch` creates the file, and this doesn't.

Answer (score 28):

My 2 cents, based on [@Joe.M answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15721565/1582182)

```
public static void touch(File file) throws IOException{
    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    touch(file, timestamp);
}

public static void touch(File file, long timestamp) throws IOException{
    if (!file.exists()) {
       new FileOutputStream(file).close();
    }

    file.setLastModified(timestamp);
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Since `File` is [a bad abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211970/filesystem-independent-file-and-path-in-java), it is better to use `Files` and `Path`:

```
public static void touch(final Path path) throws IOException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(path, "path is null");
    try {
        Files.createFile(path);
    } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException e) {
        Files.setLastModifiedTime(path, FileTime.from(Instant.now()));
    }
}
```

Comment: `Files.createFile(Path)` also checks for existence of the file. This check and the creation are an atomic operation. I think it’s better to always use `Files.createFile(Path)` and use `Files.setLastModifiedTime` if a `java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException` is thrown. Or use `Path.toFile().createNewFile()` which also does the check and creation in an atomic operation, but uses a `boolean` return code instead of an exception to indicate if the file already existed.

Comment: @Martin Good point. I have updated the answer to be atomic. It still might fail if (somehow) the file is deleted between the `try` and `catch` though.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a simple snippet:

```
void touch(File file, long timestamp)
{
    try
    {
        if (!file.exists())
            new FileOutputStream(file).close();
        file.setLastModified(timestamp);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `file.createNewFile()` instead of `new FileOutputStream(file).close()`?

Answer (score 8):

I know [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) has a [Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/touch.html) which does just that.
See the [source code of Touch](http://www.koders.com/java/fid0D95C993B2C23BECC5EB56E309FB35714823DDBF.aspx) (which can show you how they do it)

They use [`FILE_UTILS.setFileLastModified(file, modTime);`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/tools/ant/util/FileUtils.java.html), which uses [`ResourceUtils.setLastModified(new FileResource(file), time);`](http://docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/tools/ant/util/ResourceUtils.java.html), which uses a [`org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Touchable`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/tools/ant/types/resources/Touchable.java.html), implemented by [`org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.FileResource`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/tools/ant/types/resources/FileResource.java.html)...

Basically, it is a call to `File.setLastModified(modTime)`.

Answer (score 6):

This question only mentions updating the timestamp, but I thought I'd put this in here anyways. I was looking for touch like in Unix which will also create a file if it doesn't exist.

For anyone using Apache Commons, there's [`FileUtils.touch(File file)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#touch%28java.io.File%29) that does just that.

Here's the [source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/io/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java?view=markup) from (inlined `openInputStream(File f)`):

```
public static void touch(final File file) throws IOException {
    if (file.exists()) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IOException("File '" + file + "' exists but is a directory");
        }
        if (file.canWrite() == false) {
            throw new IOException("File '" + file + "' cannot be written to");
        }
    } else {
        final File parent = file.getParentFile();
        if (parent != null) {
            if (!parent.mkdirs() && !parent.isDirectory()) {
                throw new IOException("Directory '" + parent + "' could not be created");
            }
        }
        final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
    }
    final boolean success = file.setLastModified(System.currentTimeMillis());
    if (!success) {
        throw new IOException("Unable to set the last modification time for " + file);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a race condition between the file.exists and file.setLastModified calls. I.e. this code gets it backwards: FIRST you go ahead and try, THEN you do the post-mortem diagnostics.

Answer (score 6):

If you are already using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava):

`com.google.common.io.Files.touch(file)`