# Cannot Create normal File.txt with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem that I can't create a normal file !
this is my code :

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File myFile = new File("word.txt");
        System.out.println("Attempting to read from file in: "+myFile.getCanonicalPath());

        Scanner input = new Scanner(myFile);
        String in = "";
        in = input.nextLine();
    }

}
```

I have this error:

```
Attempting to read from file in: C:\Users\AHMED\workspace\Video\word.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: word.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at test.main(test.java:11)
```

Comment: ... so does that file exist?

Comment: And what is so hard to understand about this error? You're trying to read from a file that doesn't exist, so what do you expect other than an exception?

Comment: Well, I guess it is not the "normal" way to create a file by trying to read from it. Search for one the thousand tutorials about creating files using Java.

Comment: I am curious about the fact that he created the file and he wants to read from the same file. Why wasn't the file created?

Comment: I don't know really ! I working with Sphinx project but I noticed that is unable to read any directory ... So I test it with just create a new file but it doesnt work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
File myFile = new File("word.txt");
```

does not create a new file on disk. It just creates a File object in memory.

So when you try to read from the file, it doesn't exist (on disk), hence your error.

To actually create a real file on disk, you need to write data to it, or create an empty file by "touching" the file:

- [Java: how to create and write to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/java-how-to-create-and-write-to-a-file)
- [Simulate touch command with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406473/simulate-touch-command-with-java)