# Filesystem independent File and Path in Java?

Tags: java, file, unit-testing

I am using Java 8 to write an application that interacts with the file-system. To make testing easier, I am injecting a `FileSystem` into my methods, which can be swapped-out for testing. I am currently using `jimfs` in my unit-tests and `DefaultFileSystem.getFileSystem()` in production.

I would like my code to be platform independent and portable between unit-tests and production, however, I think that the classes in the standard library may prevent this.

For example, `java.io.File` contains this:

```
private static final FileSystem fs = DefaultFileSystem.getFileSystem();
```

It seems that `File` will always refer to real files, which is a problem for my unit-tests.

`Path`, on the other hand, is just an interface, which should make things easy, except it has a method to create a `File`!

```
File toFile();
```

- Which Java classes are tied to the real file-system?
- What are my options for writing `Filesystem` portable code?

Comment: The java classes tied to the real file system are the implementations of Path provided by the jre and are environment-dependent.

Comment: Does seem really odd that `File` seems to point at `WinNTFileSystem` always? Which seems to have changed in Java 8.

Comment: `Path`s [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toFile--) states that `toFile` throws an exception when the path is not tied to the default provider. It seems that this method is optional when implementing it yourself.

Comment: @JornVernee Interesting! Unfortunately many libraries (e.g. Guava) take `File` rather than a Filesystem-independent alternative (e.g. stream).

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have time to post an actual answer now, but you should look at the javadoc of `java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider`, that should be a good start

Comment: Still seems to me that the Java design of the `File` class is odd...surly there should be a constructor to create a file for a different `FileSystem`. And interestingly in Java 7 the default was acquired using a native method `public static native FileSystem getFileSystem();`