# Issue Clearing cache in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, spring, browser-cache

I have a Java/Spring MVC WebApp using Angular as the Front End. The ui application is deployed as part of the web app in the src>main>webapp folder. The problem is when I make any changes in the CSS or HTML files, the same are not reflected instantaneously. I have tried clearing cache and hard resetting also but to no avail.

I tried running the app in incognito mode too but it does not work.

Please help.

Comment: press ctrl +f5 to clear cache and check your css is updated or not

Answer (score -1):

Specific resources can be reloaded individually if you change the date and time on your files on the server. **"Clearing cache"** is not as easy as it should be. Instead of clearing cache on my browsers, I realized that "touching" the server files cached will actually change the date and time of the source file cached on the server (Tested on Edge, Chrome and Firefox) and most browsers will automatically download the most current fresh copy of whats on your server (code, graphics any multimedia too). I suggest you just copy the most current scripts on the server and **"do the touch thing"** solution before your program runs, so it will change the date of all your problem files to a most current date and time, then it downloads a fresh copy to your browser:

```
    <?php
    touch('/www/sample/file1.css');
    touch('/www/sample/file2.css');
    touch('/www/sample/file2.css'); 
    ?>
```

then ... the rest of your program...

It took me some time to resolve this issue (as many browsers act differently to different commands, but they all check time of files and compare to your downloaded copy in your browser, if different date and time, will do the refresh), If you can't go the supposed right way, there is always another usable and better solution to it. Best Regards and happy camping. By the way touch(); or alternatives work in many programming languages inclusive in javascript bash sh php and you can include or call them in html.

Comment: The solution may be relevant with PHP. I am not quite sure of Java. And what do you mean when you say change date and time on files. Thanks.

Comment: It does work with Javascript as it has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406473/simulate-touch-command-with-java

Also I used it with sh bash and other programing languages. If you acomplish just "a touch" without any modifications to the files, but just the current date and time, the browser thinks its a new version of the file and inmediately downloads the current version and replaces de old version on your browsers, tested on current Edge, Chrome and FFox Best regards... NOTE: For it to work, it needs to be the first thing it does at the beginning of your code.

Comment: @Luis JavaScript is really not the same as Java. `touch` is a common Unix command, that php wraps. JavaScript, without Node, does not generally have access to the filesystem, so no, it can't touch files.

Comment: Use a bash script to call the touch, It works, I have them on my routers to clear cache for users even before the program runs. It works. I have them installed on all my routers.